# Error "could not detect network" when using WebSocket provider with Alchemy

Tags: node.js, ethereum, ethers.js, alchemy

I have a file with over 1 million+ ethereum addresses and private keys grouped together in a single file separated only using a ','.

Example:

0x7256bCf73C2309893AA12d6b26A142AB3097560c,0x5281130a3a84f531a1e30649a881207a65ce17fae084e0ae6e78xxxxxxxxxxxx

I want to use nodejs to check the balances of each address in the line to be greater than 0.000 and then export the valid addresses along with private keys to another file.

I always experience this error whenever I run my script.

```
        var error = new Error(message);
                    ^

Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.6.8)
    at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\Asus\Downloads\eth-fast-mnemonic-checker-main\eth-fast-mnemonic-checker-main\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:233:21)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\Asus\Downloads\eth-fast-mnemonic-checker-main\eth-fast-mnemonic-checker-main\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:242:20)
    at WebSocketProvider.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Asus\Downloads\eth-fast-mnemonic-checker-main\eth-fast-mnemonic-checker-main\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:561:54)
    at step (C:\Users\Asus\Downloads\eth-fast-mnemonic-checker-main\eth-fast-mnemonic-checker-main\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.throw (C:\Users\Asus\Downloads\eth-fast-mnemonic-checker-main\eth-fast-mnemonic-checker-main\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:29:53)
    at rejected (C:\Users\Asus\Downloads\eth-fast-mnemonic-checker-main\eth-fast-mnemonic-checker-main\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\json-rpc-provider.js:21:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  reason: 'could not detect network',
  code: 'NETWORK_ERROR',
  event: 'noNetwork'
}
```

Here's the initial script , would be grateful if you could fix the error for me, thanks.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const ethers = require('ethers')
require('colors')

const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(
    'wss://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/k5d8RoDGOyxZmVWy2UPNxxxxxxxxxxxx'
)

const addresses = fs
    .readFileSync('hits.txt', 'utf8')
    .split('\n')
    .map((val) => {
        return val.split(',')
    })

;(async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
        const address = addresses[i][0]
        const balance = await provider.getBalance(address)

        if (balance.gt(0)) {
            console.log(address.bgGreen.black, balance.toString().bgGreen.black)
            console.log('Private Key: '.yellow, addresses[i][1])
        } else {
            console.log(address, 0)
        }
    }
})()
```

Comment: Don't leak your API key!

Comment: oops , can I edit the post?

Comment: Yes but it will stay in the post history, and also it can already be indexed by SO scrapers and such. We'll have to flag it for a moderator to remove it from history. It will be better if you just ditch this key and create a new key in Alchemy.

Comment: I think it's fine to just leave it there , it's an old key. I'm just looking to fix the error.

Comment: I posted an answer below. You are missing `ws.` in the domain.

Comment: The domain can't be found , I'm suddenly getting another error

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong endpoint domain.

According to [the docs](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/best-practices-for-using-websockets-in-web3), the domain of the endpoint for WebSocket connections is eth-mainnet.**ws**.g.alchemy.com (note the extra `ws` in there). However, that domain doesn't seem to exist! Perhaps the docs are outdated... I found [another source](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereum-org-website/issues/1925) which instead shows the correct domain as `eth-mainnet.ws.alchemyapi.io` which does exist.

Maybe also check within your Alchemy account, the correct URL should be shown there as well.

Comment: Nope , I get another error saying the domain can't be found

Comment: errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'eth-mainnet.ws.g.alchemy.com
}

Comment: See my edit please.

Comment: I still receive the same error I initially did with the initial domain

Comment: Then I think you should ask Alchemy support for help. Also, you will get more targeted help on the [Ethereum Stack Exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com) than here.